# Фоновые блоки при подключенном bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

[image: Блоки, какие нужны]

Как сделать такие же блоки с бэкграундом, если вся вёрстка сделана на бутстрапе?

Comment: Вам всю страницу целиком нужно сверстать?

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно, чтоб содержимое контейнера растягивалось на всю ширину экрана, то используйте `.container-fluid` вместе `.container`